# Orocrm - Web API OAuth, request returns 401

Tags: oauth-2.0, guzzle, orocrm

As the title states, i'm getting a 401 response whenever i try to request any endpoint from the webservice API (i'm running orocrm 4.1 and public + private keys were generated and placed in /var with the right name).

#### 1. Created an OAuth application

Grant type = client_credentials (the chosen user has all admin rights) :
[image]

#### 2. Get the token (using GuzzleHttp client)

```php
$base_uri = 'https://mywebsite.com';
$generate_token_endpoint = '/oauth2-token';
$grant_type = 'client_credentials';
$client_id = '###############################';
$client_secret = '#################################';

$client = new Client(array(
    'base_uri' => $base_uri,
     'headers' => array(
          'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.api+json'
      )
 ));

$response = $client->post($generate_token_endpoint, array(
    'form_params' => array(
          'grant_type' => $grant_type,
          'client_id' => $client_id,
          'client_secret' => $client_secret
     )
));

$tokenJson = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$token = 'Bearer '.$tokenJson['access_token'];

// The actual request to get some data
$response = $client->get('/api/users', array(
     'headers' => array(
          'Authorization' => $token
      )
));
```

I do receive a token, i even extended it's lifetime, but then the next request's result is (no matter what i do) :

```
Client error: 'GET https://mywebsite.com/api/users' resulted in a '401 Unauthorized' response
```

I also tried using POSTMAN, but the result is the same.

**HELP !**

Answer (score 1):

Please generate the public.key or private.key and store to var folder like:

```
app folder / var / oauth_private.key
app folder / var / oauth_public.key
```

you can follow the below step:

1. openssl genrsa -out oauth_private.key 2048
2. openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out oauth_public.key
3. then move to var folder

reference link

```
https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/installation/#generating-public-and-private-keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, you generated encryption keys correctly and placed them to the var folder with appropriate names: https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/user-management/oauth-app/#starting-conditions
When keys are not configured properly, on a page with oAuth applications, you will see the warning

> OAuth authorization is not available as encryption keys configuration
>   was not complete. Please contact your administrator.

If the keys are there, you have to check application logs for errors after authentication. Also, check the response from the server. Usually, it has some hints on what is wrong.